# Turn on cyclmatic complexity in JSHint

Tags: javascript, jshint, cyclomatic-complexity

I am using JSHint and I want to turn on cyclomatic complexity.
From [JsHint homepage](https://jshint.com/) and [JsHint Docs](https://jshint.com/docs/options/#maxcomplexity) , JsHint seem to be able to measure it.
But after I ran this command `jshint test.js` to test the below file

```
//test.js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("p").click(function() {
        $(this).hide();
        var x = 5
    });

    function main() {
        return 'Hello, World!';
    }
});
```

I only get the linting report (test.js: line 4, col 14, Missing semicolon., ...)

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [API docs](https://jshint.com/docs/api/), it looks like you can call `JSHINT.data()` after linting to get the metrics, which includes measuring complexity:

> **JSHINT.data()**
>
> Generate a report containing details about the most recent invocation of JSHINT.
>
> For example, the following code:

```
var source = [
  'function goo() {}',
  'foo = 3;'
];
var options = {
  undef: true
};
var predef = {
  foo: false
};

JSHINT(source, options, predef);

console.log(JSHINT.data());
```

> ...will produce the following output:

```
{
  functions: [
    {
      name: 'goo',
      // ...
      metrics: {
        complexity: 1,
        parameters: 0,
        statements: 0
      }
      // ...
```

This will display the measured complexity.

Note that this is completely separate from the [maxcomplexity](https://jshint.com/docs/options/#maxcomplexity) rule - if enabled, and you set it low enough, and you have a function complex enough, your linting output will include an error.